# Pagination of plain HTML files

Tags: html, pagination

I have in root folders with index.html files in them:

```
/2/index.html
/3/index.html
/4/index.html
/5/index.html
…
/467/index.html
/468/index.html
…
/lastpagenumber/index.html
```

How to create a pagination script that creates URLs from these folders' names (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` … `467`, `468` … `lastpagenumber`)? In other words I need somehow to parse server to create URLs and detect on which page user is at the moment. So I wanna have on every page a simple kind of pagination like:

**1** 2 3 next page  last page

previous page 1 2 **3** 4 5 next page  last page

**467** 469 468 last page

Comment: I ask how to do that because I don't know how to.

Comment: i am writing a answer, pls be pacient

Comment: With plain HTML you can't do this, do you have a server-side script you can use? ([tag:php], [tag:ruby], [tag:asp.net]...)

Comment: true, you need php/sql or something; but as i understand, he has something, he does not know how to generate the pagination

Comment: I have php and mysql on the server. But I'm not good in php. I need straight simple explanation example to understand how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the entire article, and then, try to do it in your style;

The article is simple:

1. try and catch the actual page value, if sent thru GET, step 6
2. set a max articles per page value
3. query a database table, and etract all articles needed
4. see how many pages you have: ceil(total_articles/articles_per_page)
5. use a for loop ito print the pages
6. send via GET the page number, on button click event, and go to step 1 again

source: [pagination](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I do not think it would be possible to do it with plain HTML since you would have to perform some evaluations.

What you can do, is to put a java script on top and create a loop that would do it "manually". You should have the `<div>` in all pages and javascript put in separate script.js file and refer to it from all html pages. Therefore all pages will refer to one script where you can adjust amount of pages manually (468 in out case)

Check it out and let meknow if it works:

```
<div id="pages"> </div>

<script>
    getCurrentPage();

    function getCurrentPage(){

        currentPage = getDirectoryName();
        for (i=0; i<468; i++){
            curdoc = document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML;
            if (i==(currentPage*1)){
                 createLink = ' <a href=/'+i+'/index.html><b>'+i+'</b></a> | ';
                document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML = curdoc+ '' +createLink;
            }else{
                createLink = ' <a href=/'+i+'/index.html>'+i+'</a> | ';
                document.getElementById("pages").innerHTML = curdoc+ '' +createLink;
            }
        }
    }

    function getDirectoryName(){
        var file, n;
        file = window.location.pathname;
        pathArray = file.split("/");
        directoryName = pathArray[(pathArray.length)-2];
        return(directoryName);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Nice, but if always manually change this number of last page that's easier simply to add every time one link of new page. And also it shows all pages in pagination. It doesn't recognize four next and previous pages.

Comment: You can't "get" the list of directories from the server (assuming your project is run on some sort of web server) since the JavaScript is a Client-side language('compiled' in your browser). To start doing some sort of server-side work, you would have to implement the server-side programming (PHP example). I assume that I should not continue working on above solution since you decided to `add links`. PS - very lousy design and solution. Learn some simple php and you could do it easy and without problems `the right way`